# mod rewrite losing post variables ajax

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod rewrite for my URL's.  I have a form that is submitted through ajax, however the post variables are not being passed.  I am trying to post from home.php to new_post.php

Is there a way to exclude the new_post.php file from using the rules below? So that the variables can be passed. I tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^new_post.php / [L,R=301]
```

I am using the following in my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^new_post\.php$ / [L,NC]
```

I am submitting a form from home.php to new_post.php through AJAX.  new_post.php inserts the data into mysql, after the data is inserted, I echo the new url that the user should be redirected to as:

```
echo "post.php?id=$id";
```

In AJAX success I use location(data); to redirect the user to the new post.

There are two problems:

The url redirects to an ACCESS FORBIDDEN message from xampp and the post variables are not passed

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules in this order:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^post\.php$ / [L,NC]
```

Comment: tried this but the variables are still not being passed

Comment: You have to clear your browser cache completely. What is full URL coming for AJAX request?

Comment: ajax url is new_post.php

Comment: then I echo the new url in the ajax php file echo "post.php?id=$id", then location(data) in ajax but this is being redirected to mydomain.com/<!DOCTYPE

Comment: Didn't understand your comment, Exact same code works on my Apache and preserves all POST data. You have some other code/config issue.

Comment: Comment all lines below `RewriteBase /` and keep only last line `RewriteRule ^new_post\.php$ / [L,NC]` uncommented. Then test and see.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: That proves that problem is in your code not in rules.

Comment: It is not working due to your code as I have already told exact same rules work on my Apache and preserve POST variables. Besides you're also getting `ACCESS FORBIDDEN` error

Comment: its a 404 xhr error, cant find jquery - i have checked the path and its correct - not sure why that error is shown

Comment: my code and error are similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699925/using-ajax-and-a-remote-php-to-upload-files

Comment: That error is due to remote AJAX which is not the case with you I believe.